# How can I review my reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-history

The stupid test post caught me out. Obviously, this is not the first time, as for some reason I got a two-day ban. This seems harsh, but hey, I'm cool with that. What I can't seem to find is, how do I review my reviews, and look to see what else it feels I must have gotten wrong?

Being dyslexic is a pain in the fluff. It would not surprise me too much to find that I did wrong, but I'd like to try to learn from it.

Comment: Click your profile -> Main User -> Activity tab -> all actions -> reviews,  http://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder?tab=activity&sort=reviews. And I'm sorry, but [if you approve edits like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9202612) you should really try to read more carefully.

Comment: Thanks, that doesnt seem to include whether it counted as "good" or "bad" though

Comment: As I said, I got caught out by the test poster..

Comment: Every review, once reviewed by enough people, will show you the outcome of whether it was accepted or not. It says _"Review audit failed 13 mins ago"_ at the audit review.

Comment: That test linked by CodeCaster is a typical review audit. It's a classic case of adding random words, that should've been a red flag the moment you saw the diff. Just make sure you learn from it, I'd say...

Comment: Guys seriously, you clearly dont understand how dyslexia can work - I do read them, I reject plenty of things, and skip past ones I dont feel I should answer. I clicked accept because when I read it, it made sense to me.  So, I posted here, openly admitting that the test post caught me out. Im kinda sad you feel that you need to rip into me when I havent come here claiming I shouldnt have been banned. I came to ask how to review myself and learn.

Comment: @bugFinder how does dyslexia makes THIS : "Many thanks for any subdirectory got those two file for each a lots of help," make sense?

Comment: you're reading it as you, you're not reading it as me.

Comment: @BugFinder then if your dyslexia is that problematic... maybe not reviewing is in order? No offense intended, but if that sentence can make sense to you, I don't see how you can do effective reviewing

Comment: I do not know how dyslexia works - this is true. If your dyslexia makes it hard for you to do reviews, maybe you should ask for help when reviewing? Or could it help if you had a text-to-speech tool?

Comment: It probably would help with a text to speech tool, but, not here in the office.  I shall skip doing reviews in future. I was trying to help, but clearly, Im not.  I am a bit upset by the attitudes shown as I had best intentions and was not coming here in a demanding or outraged mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The history of your reviews is stored per queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history

Also, as @CodeCaster pointed out, there is your review history on your profile page:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder?tab=activity&sort=reviews

These don't tell you if a review was "good" or "bad", because the point of a review is to bring in a human factor. If we could determine automatically if an action was good or bad, we would not need review queues.

You can, however, see if you failed an audit.

Comment: Awesome thats just what I wanted the top link.